# Ubuntu no longer works after VirtualBox update

Tags: virtualbox

I just updated my VirutalBox to the latest software, and since then I cannot get Ubuntu to load. It black screens on the login screen. I've tried several fixes other forums have mentioned such as the graphics settings, the number of processors, and switching between views, but nothing has worked yet. I know my Ubuntu was slightly out of date, but not sure if that would cause an issue as it worked fine before. Windows is the host.

Below is a link to the zip of the logs for the Ubuntu machine, in case that helps with diagnosing the issue. Thanks for the help!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qimC7wZu3qORY3tZNEh9Onb94tx1xcPP/view?usp=sharing

Edit: Windows 10 is Host, Ubuntu 20.04 is guest

Comment: What is your host system. Which Ubuntu Version is your Guest system? I just can't find my crystal ball...

Comment: Windows 10 is host, Ubuntu 20.04 is guest

Comment: Does the login screen work, or is it already black? Btw: It is good style to add those information into your question (use the **Edit** link) instead of adding each bit into a comment...

Comment: The login screen is already black. Some people had mentioned they could still type in their password and it would log them in (fixing the black screen), but I have not been able to do that in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your settings may not be not correct. See my settings for Ubuntu (on a Linux host) and compare:
Ubuntu seems only to run in VMSVGA Mode, 3D must be enabled:

[[image: 1]]

Comment: My settings look similar, though I have tried varying the video memory. I created a fresh Ubuntu VM on a new partition, with the same settings, and everything seems to work fine. So, updating VirtualBox may have done something to my other partitions? I was able to access them by adding them as secondary drives to the new Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since your infos about your system are rather sparse, I can't answer your question, but updating VB should've helped